# How to access a List<> property of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, collections, webforms

I am basically filling a repeater with the **Restaurant** information.

```
class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; };
    public string Name { get; set; };
    public List<Category> RestaurantCategory { get; set; };
    public string Address { get; set; };
}

class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; };
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; };
    public string CategoryName { get; set; };
}
```

And the name of my repeater is `rptRestaurantInfo`:

```
rptRestaurantInfo.DataSource = RestaurantData; //RestaurantData is of type List<Restaurant>
rptRestaurantInfo.DataBind();
```

What I want to do is, the `<table>` in which I want to display my repeater data, I want to show the category name(s) associated with each restaurant.

How can I access the values of `List<Category>`?

What I've tried:

Looping through each `Restaurant` item. Storing the value of the item in a list of type `Category`:

```
    foreach(var restaurant in RestaurantData)
    {
        restaurant.instanceOfCategory. // properties of Category do not appear
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using datatables which makes it easy to bind.  Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Restaurant> RestaurantData = new List<Restaurant>();

            DataTable rptRestaurantInfo = new DataTable();
            rptRestaurantInfo.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            rptRestaurantInfo.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            rptRestaurantInfo.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
            rptRestaurantInfo.Columns.Add("CategoryId", typeof(int));
            rptRestaurantInfo.Columns.Add("RestaurantId", typeof(int));
            rptRestaurantInfo.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(string));

            foreach(Restaurant restaurant in RestaurantData)
            {
                foreach(Category category in restaurant.RestaurantCategory)
                {
                    rptRestaurantInfo.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        restaurant.Id,
                        restaurant.Name,
                        restaurant.Address,
                        category.CategoryId,
                        category.RestaurantId,
                        category.CategoryName
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Category> RestaurantCategory { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```